# Problems with data binding on dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm getting an exception telling me "Binding' cannot be set on the 'InitialStartDateTime' property of type 'WinFormsWrapper'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject." but my properties are dependency properties as you can see here, right?

```
public class WinFormsWrapper : WindowsFormsHost
{       
    /// <summary>
    /// The control element
    /// </summary>
    private static EtDateTimeRange control = new EtDateTimeRange();     

    /// <summary>
    /// The dependency property for InitialStartDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialStartDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StartDateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(WinFormsWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(control.InitialStartDateTime, new PropertyChangedCallback(InitialStartDateTime_Changed)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">The arguments</param>
    private static void InitialStartDateTime_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        control.InitialStartDateTime = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, sets the InitialStartDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime InitialStartDateTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(InitialStartDateTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InitialStartDateTimeProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The dependency property for InitialEndDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialEndDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EndDateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(WinFormsWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(control.InitialEndDateTime, new PropertyChangedCallback(InitialEndDateTime_Changed)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">The arguments</param>
    private static void InitialEndDateTime_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //_control.InitialEndDateTime = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, sets the InitialEndDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime InitialEndDateTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(InitialEndDateTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InitialEndDateTimeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and this is my xaml:

```
<controls:WinFormsWrapper InitialStartDateTime="{Binding StartDateTime}" InitialEndDateTime="{Binding EndDateTime}" />
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Thanks alot, its running now, but it's still not displaying my control, any ideas why?

Comment: Your control is not set as Content right ? So WPF has nothing to display

Comment: right but theres no content attribute for my WinFormsWrapper?

Comment: Use Child Property :)

Comment: like this <controls:WinFormsWrapper Child="{Binding Source={x:Static control}}"... /> ? Its not working because the control is not a property in my viewmodel

Comment: Set it in your WinFormsWrapper constructor. this.Child = control;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DependencyProperty.Register("StartDateTime",
```

You have to Name it

```
 DependencyProperty.Register("InitialStartDateTime",
```

:)

Same Problem with the EndDateTime

I hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong properties in your DependencyProperty creation.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialEndDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EndDateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(WinFormsWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(control.InitialEndDateTime, new PropertyChangedCallback(InitialEndDateTime_Changed)));
```

In the Register part, it should have been `InitialEndDateTime` instead of `EndDateTime`.